# Updating record with Oracle SQL results in an infinite loop while using a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, database-cursor

I am stuck in infinite loop while using a cursor to update a record. Here is the code... Any suggestions of what should i do?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHADI.filling_conditional
as
  cursor filling_cursor is select * from deposits_table for update;
begin 
  for i in filling_cursor 
  loop       
       update deposits_table 
         set conditional_flag = case 
                                    when i.deposit_amount > 1000 and i.currency_code = 'JOD'
                                         and (select customer_info.sex 
                                              from customer_info 
                                              where customer_info.customer_number = i.customer_number) = 1 
                                       then 1
                                    else 0 
                                 end;

  end loop;
end filling_conditional;
/
```

Comment: No need for a cursor.

Comment: And if you really want to use the slowest possible way to update a table, you should at least use `where current of` in your `update` statement. Currently every iteration of the cursor updates **all** rows in the table - I am pretty sure this is not what you want.

Comment: I am new to oracle, i need to implement this procedure as a cursor for a practice. Any Ideas? Thank you for your response.

Comment: That is a strange "practice" that teaches inefficient things.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your response, I am new to Oracle. the main idea is to iterate every row in the deposits_table that matches the conditions above written. and update them accordingly

Comment: As I said: you have to use `where current of` otherwise you update **all** rows in deposits_table for every iteration of the cursor.

Comment: Where should i place it? in my code i did use case statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHADI.filling_conditional
as
   c_deposit_amount   deposits_table.deposit_amount%type; 
   c_currency_code deposits_table.currency_code%type; 
   c_customer_number deposits_table.customer_number%type; 
   cursor filling_cursor is select deposit_amount, currency_code, customer_number from deposits_table for update;
BEGIN 
   OPEN filling_cursor; 
   LOOP 
   FETCH filling_cursor into c_deposit_amount, c_currency_code, c_customer_number; 
      EXIT WHEN filling_cursor%notfound; 
      update deposits_table 
         set conditional_flag = case 
                                    when c_deposit_amount > 1000 and c_currency_code = 'JOD'
                                         and (select customer_info.sex 
                                              from customer_info 
                                              where customer_info.customer_number = c_customer_number) = 1 
                                       then 1
                                    else 0 
                                 end;
   END LOOP; 
   CLOSE filling_cursor; 
END filling_conditional;
/
```

Comment: The following code produces an error as the following: 
[Error] PLS-00324 (11: 17): PLS-00324: cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'C_CUSTOMER_NUMBER'

Comment: The error produced on this line:  EXIT WHEN c_deposit_amount%notfound;

Comment: Just update code as per below: "EXIT WHEN c_deposit_amount%notfound;  =>  "EXIT WHEN filling_cursor%notfound; "

Comment: This is still updating **all** rows in `deposits_table` for every iteration because the UPDATE has no WHERE clause